# How can I find out why a particular Maven package is being included?

Tags: java, maven

Given a Maven project, how can I tell which of its immediate dependencies is causing a particular transitive dependency to be brought in?

E.g., I have a module that has a number of `<dependency>`s from Maven Central, and each of those has its own dependencies, etc. When I build, it's pulling in a (transitive) dependency I didn't expect.

How can I find out which of my module's immediate dependencies is causing transitive library-X-version-Y to be pulled in? Ideally I'd like to see the whole chain (or multiple chains if applicable), e.g. `xyz:1.0.0 -> uvw:32.1 -> rst:9.9 -> abc:1.2.3`, or anything else to help me figure out why this dependency is there.

Comment: Does this help? [Maven dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mvn dependency:tree` will give you the output you're looking for.

Comment: That failed partway through for me, with "Could not resolve dependencies for project X: Could not find artifact Y", because I have a multi-module project with some modules depending on others. But if I add a compile step - `mvn test-compile dependency:tree` - then it runs successfully.